# Number of unique subgroupings of a set containing duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

Given the set $\{A,A,B,B,C\}$, there are eight different ways to create three unique, non-empty subgroups from it:
$\{A\},\{B\},\{A,B,C\}$
$\{A\},\{C\},\{A,B,B\}$
$\{B\},\{C\},\{A,A,B\}$
$\{A\},\{A,B\},\{B,C\}$
$\{A\},\{A,C\},\{B,B\}$
$\{B\},\{A,A\},\{B,C\}$
$\{B\},\{A,B\},\{A,C\}$
$\{C\},\{A,A\},\{B,B\}$

Note that these groupings are not allowed, since not all of their subgroups are unique:
$\{A\},\{A\},\{B,B,C\}$ (duplicate A)
$\{B\},\{B\},\{A,A,C\}$ (duplicate B)
$\{C\},\{A,B\},\{A,B\}$ (duplicate A,B)

I can determine this by hand, but it is tedious and I'm sure there's a better mathematical approach. Given an arbitrary set, how can I determine the number of ways to create $n$ unique, non-empty subgroups from it?

I don't need to generate the subgroups themselves, just find how many there are.

Comment: Are you only allowed to use as many $A$'s in your subgrouping as there are in the original set?  Must you use all the elements of the original set in the partitioning?

Comment: So really, what you are asking is: "How many ways can the original set $A$ be partitioned into $n$ distinct multi-sets?"

Comment: All elements must be used once when partitioning. Yes, I'm looking for the number of unique ways to partition the set.

Comment: This seems like it'll be quite hard to give a general formula, just because the formula would have to take into account the possible diversity of number of distinct elements in the original set, how many of each, ... etc.  For a specific starting set and $n$, you may be able to find a nice way to count it, but I doubt the method will generalize well.

Comment: I was hoping this would be some well-known pattern (e.g. combinations, permutations) but I guess it's more specific than I expected. I suppose I'll have to [find all of the partitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530128/how-to-find-all-partitions-of-a-set), remove the ones with too many/few partitions, then remove the ones with duplicate multisets. Thanks for helping me with the terminology!